# How to compare with values adjacent in a sequence in the same group

Tags: r

Let's say I have something like this:

```
set.seed(0)
the.df <- data.frame( x=rep(letters[1:3], each=4),
                        n=rep(0:3, 3),
                        val=round(runif(12)))
the.df


   x n val
1  a 0   1
2  a 1   0
3  a 2   0
4  a 3   1
5  b 0   1
6  b 1   0
7  b 2   1
8  b 3   1
9  c 0   1
10 c 1   1
11 c 2   0
12 c 3   0
```

Within each `x`, starting from `n==2` (going from small to large), I want to set `val` to 0 if the previous `val` (in terms of `n`) is 0; otherwise, leave it as is.

For example, in the subset `x=="b"`, I first ignore the two rows where `n` < 2. Now, in Row 7, because the previous `val` is 0 (`the.df$val[the.df$x=="b" & the.df$n==1]`), I set `val` to 0 (`the.df$val[the.df$x=="b" & the.df$n==2] <- 0`). Then on Row 8, now that `val` for the previous `n` is 0 (we just set it), I also want to set `val` here to 0 (`the.df$val[the.df$x=="b" & the.df$n==3] <- 0`).

Imagine that the `data.frame` is not sorted. Therefore procedures that depend on the order would require a sort. I also can't assume that adjacent rows exist (e.g., the row `the.df[the.df$x=="a" & the.df$n==1, ]` might be missing).

The trickiest part seems to be evaluating `val` in sequence. I can do this using a loop but I imagine that it would be inefficient (I have millions of rows). Is there a way I can do this more efficiently?

EDIT: wanted output

```
the.df

   x n val wanted
1  a 0   1      1
2  a 1   0      0
3  a 2   0      0
4  a 3   1      0
5  b 0   1      1
6  b 1   0      0
7  b 2   1      0
8  b 3   1      0
9  c 0   1      1
10 c 1   1      1
11 c 2   0      0
12 c 3   0      0
```

Also, I don't mind making new columns (e.g., putting the wanted values there).

Comment: When you say 'previous val is 0` you mean `x=b and n=1` or `x=a and n=2`?

Comment: @Sotos `x==b` and `n==1`. Rows with different `x` are not referenced at all.

Comment: You could start from a `data.table::shift()` function: `the.df[n > 1 & shift(val, 1L, type = "lag") == 0, val := 0]`, but it is not using the recently updated `val` values...

Answer (score 6):

Using `data.table` I would try the following

```
library(data.table)
setDT(the.df)[order(n), 
          val := if(length(indx <- which(val[2:.N] == 0L))) 
            c(val[1:(indx[1L] + 1L)], rep(0L, .N - (indx[1L] + 1L))), 
          by = x]
the.df
#     x n val
#  1: a 0   1
#  2: a 1   0
#  3: a 2   0
#  4: a 3   0
#  5: b 0   1
#  6: b 1   0
#  7: b 2   0
#  8: b 3   0
#  9: c 0   1
# 10: c 1   1
# 11: c 2   0
# 12: c 3   0
```

This will simultaneously order the data by `n` (as you said it's not ordered in real life) and recreate `val` by condition (meaning that if condition not satisfied, `val` will be untouched).

---

Hopefully in the near future [this](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/571) will be implemented and then the code could potentially be

```
setDT(the.df)[order(n), val[n > 2] := if(val[2L] == 0) 0L, by = x]
```

Which could be a great improvement both performance and syntax wise

Comment: brilliant, I have focused on avoiding the direct loop whereas the problem was much simpler - if there is one row to change, change all the rest within this particular x group.

Comment: Sorry, edited the previous one by mistake. It looks like your solution is not working for `the.df <- data.table(
  x = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c"),
  n = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L),
  val = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)

Comment: @m-dz See fix and tell me what you think

Comment: @m-dz maybe, but make sure you bench on a big data set, enough unique groups and that your solution also performs ordering (as per OPs request)

Comment: Please see my edit. I am removing some previous comments from this discussion to clean it a bit.

Comment: Re that first line's `if` condition, doesn't `which.max` always return a length of one?

Comment: Wouldn't `cummin` work here? `setDT(the.df)[order(x,n), ans := cummin(val), by=x]`

Comment: @Frank, yeah you are right. I was first experiencing with `which` which returns `integer(0)` in case condition wasn't met

Comment: @Arun this looks like a winner. Thought he problem with this solution is that if there are zeroes in the first value in a certain group- it will return wrong results. Though it seems like Martin handled that case

Answer (score 3):

A base R approach might be

```
df <- the.df[order(the.df$x, the.df$n),]
df$val <- ave(df$val, df$x, FUN=fun)
```

As for `fun`, @DavidArenburg's answer in plain R and written a bit more poetically might be

```
fun0 <- function(v) {
    idx <- which.max(v[2:length(v)] == 0L) + 1L
    if (length(idx))
        v[idx:length(v)] <- 0L
    v
}
```

It seems like a good idea to formulate the solution  as an independent function first, because then it is easy to test. fun0 fails for some edge cases, e.g.,

```
> fun0(0)
[1] 0 0 0
> fun0(1)
[1] 0 0 0
> fun0(c(1, 1))
[1] 1 0
```

A better version is

```
fun1 <- function(v) {
    tst <- tail(v, -1) == 0L
    if (any(tst)) {
        idx <- which.max(tst) + 1L
        v[idx:length(v)] <- 0L
    }
    v
}
```

And even better, following @Arun

```
fun <- function(v)
    if (length(v) > 2) c(v[1], cummin(v[-1])) else v
```

This is competitive (same order of magnitude) with the data.table solution, with ordering and return occurring in less than 1s for the ~10m row data.frame of @m-dz 's timings. At a second for millions of rows, it doesn't seem worth while to pursue further optimization.

Nonetheless, when there are a very large number of small groups (e.g., 2M each of size 5) an improvement is to avoid the `tapply()` function call by using group identity to offset the minimum. For instance,

```
df <- df[order(df$x, df$n),]
grp <- match(df$x, unique(df$x))    # strictly sequential groups
keep <- duplicated(grp)             # ignore the first of each group
df$val[keep] <- cummin(df$val[keep] - grp[keep]) + grp[keep]
```

Comment: I'm still confused (continuing my comment on David's answer...): `which.max(x)+1L` has a length of zero if `x` contains only NAs and a length of one otherwise. And `v[tail(seq_along(v), -1)]` seems equivalent to `tail(v, -1)`..?

Comment: @Frank you're right about `tail()`, thanks! I think David was trying to protect against the case when `which.max()` was passed a zero-length vector, but the use of `:` means that never happens (this is the source of the bugs I point out -- `:` seems never to be the right thing to do).

Comment: My solution needed a fix because unlike `which`, `which.max` returns an index even if the condition weren't met. I've edited my answer to fix that.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I think a second test case is `the.df = data.frame(x="a", n=1, val=0)` which still fails for me (in plain R my understanding of what `2:.N` does is to create a vector `c(2, 1)` in this case).

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm, should be pretty efficient if you switch to `data.table`...

```
library(data.table)

# Define the.df as a data.table (or use data.table::setDT() function)
set.seed(0)
the.df <- data.table(
  x = rep(letters[1:3], each = 4),
  n = rep(0:3, 3),
  val = round(runif(12))
)

m_dz <- function() {
  setorder(the.df, x, n)
  repeat{
    # Get IDs of rows to change
    # ids <- which(the.df[, (n > 1) & (val == 1) & (shift(val, 1L, type = "lag") == 0)])
    ids <- the.df[(n > 1) & (val == 1) & (shift(val, 1L, type = "lag") == 0), , which = TRUE]
    # If no IDs break
    if(length(ids) == 0){
      break
    }
    # Set val to 0
    # for (i in ids) set(the.df, i = i, j = "val", value = 0)
    set(the.df, i = ids, j = "val", value = 0)
  }
  return(the.df)
}
```

#### Edit: Above function is slightly modified thanks to @jangorecki's, i.e. uses `which = TRUE` and `set(the.df, i = ids, j = "val", value = 0)`, which made the timings much more stable (no very high max timings).

#### Edit: timing comparison with @David Arenburgs's answer on a slightly bigger table, `m-dz()` updated (@FoldedChromatin's answer skipped because of diffrent results).

My function is slightly faster in terms of median and upper quantile, but there is quite a big spread in timings (see max...), I cannot figure out why. Hopefully the timing methodology is correct (returning the result to different object etc.).

Anything bigger will kill my PC :(

```
set.seed(0)
groups_ids <- replicate(300, paste(sample(LETTERS, 5, replace=TRUE), collapse = ""))

size1 <- length(unique(groups_ids))
size2 <- round(1e7/size1)

the.df1 <- data.table(
  x = rep(groups_ids, each = size2),  # 52 * 500 = 26000
  n = rep(0:(size2-1), size1), 
  val = round(runif(size1*size2))
)

the.df2 <- copy(the.df1)

# m-dz
m_dz <- function() {
  setorder(df1, x, n)
  repeat{
    ids <- df1[(n > 1) & (val == 1) & (shift(val, 1L, type = "lag") == 0), , which = TRUE]
    if(length(ids) == 0){
      break
    }
    set(df1, i = ids, j = "val", value = 0)
  }
  return(df1)
}

# David Arenburg
DavidArenburg <- function() {
  setorder(df2, x, n)
  df2[, val := if(length(indx <- which.max(val[2:.N] == 0) + 1L)) c(val[1:indx], rep(0L, .N - indx)), by = x]
  return(df2)
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  res1 <- m_dz(),
  res2 <- DavidArenburg(),
  times = 100
)

# Unit: milliseconds
#                    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
#          res1 <- m_dz() 247.4136 268.5005 363.0117 288.4216 312.7307 7071.0960   100   a
# res2 <- DavidArenburg() 270.6074 281.3935 314.7864 303.5229 328.1210  525.8095   100   a

identical(res1, res2)

# [1] TRUE
```

#### Edit: (Old) results for even bigger table:

```
set.seed(0)
groups_ids <- replicate(300, paste(sample(LETTERS, 5, replace=TRUE), collapse = ""))

size1 <- length(unique(groups_ids))
size2 <- round(1e8/size1)

# Unit: seconds
#                     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
#           res1 <- m_dz() 5.599855 5.800264 8.773817 5.923721 6.021132 289.85107   100   a
#          res2 <- m_dz2() 5.571911 5.836191 9.047958 5.970952 6.123419 310.65280   100   a
#  res3 <- DavidArenburg() 9.183145 9.519756 9.714105 9.723325 9.918377  10.28965   100   a
```

Comment: There is not point on benching on a 10 rows data set. This should be around 1e6 rows and significant amount of unique groups

Comment: Good point. I found an error in my solution, would fix it and benchmark it on something bigger.

Comment: I would say 1e7 rows at least, 1e6 rows can fit in cpu cache and heavily influence the timing.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, cannot run anything bigger now, will look at it again later.

Comment: @jangorecki, almost 1e7, hopefully this is meaningful.

Comment: `microbenchmark` runs function multiple times, while `setorder`/`setkey` changes the object by reference, so its timings is generally included only in the first run.  Sorry for being pain in the ass, just trying to educate :) In such case might be better to run it once, but here - looking at the `max` - it can also mislead the results. Yeah, benchmarking is demanding.

Comment: @jangorecki, thank you for being a pain in the ass! Shouldn't `setorder/setkey` run every time the `microbenchmark` is running the function? Is there a "flag" in `data.table` object saying if it is ordered or not? And finally, do you know why this initial ordering is not visible in `DavidArenburg()` function?

Comment: Yeah, the "flag" is an attribute. It might be sufficient to `setattr(DT, "sorted", NULL)` (which should take very little time), but Jan can correct me if that's not right.

Comment: Even if you set the flag, your input data will be already sorted so the function call will have much less to do comparing to case if you start with unsorted data in each iteration. I haven't look into actual implementation... done it now, and... 1. you may try `dt[..., which=TRUE]` instead of `which(dt[...])`, 2. you should be able to use `i` as vector in `set` function to avoid `for (i in ids)` loop.

Comment: @jangorecki, I have applied your suggestions (vectorized `set()` and `which = TRUE`) and moved ordering outside both functions and those very high max values for `m_dz()` timings are still there. Order in which functions are timed did not matter. Looks like a nice investigation for next week.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `by`

```
> set.seed(0)
> the.df <- data.frame( x=rep(letters[1:3], each=4),
                        n=rep(0:3, 3),
                        val=round(runif(12)))
> the.df
   x n val
1  a 0   1
2  a 1   0
3  a 2   0
4  a 3   1
5  b 0   1
6  b 1   0
7  b 2   1
8  b 3   1
9  c 0   1
10 c 1   1
11 c 2   0
12 c 3   0

> Mod.df<-by(the.df,INDICES=the.df$x,function(x){
    x$val[x$n==2]=0 
    Which=which(x$n==2 & x$val==0)+1 
    x$val[Which]=0 
    x})

> do.call(rbind,Mod.df)
     x n val
a.1  a 0   1
a.2  a 1   0
a.3  a 2   0
a.4  a 3   0
b.5  b 0   1
b.6  b 1   0
b.7  b 2   0
b.8  b 3   0
c.9  c 0   1
c.10 c 1   1
c.11 c 2   0
c.12 c 3   0
```